# Writing String and Double values stored in Array to a file using BufferWriter

Tags: java

I have a simple question regarding how to write my object array data into a file
Using a buffered writer, I have had no joy and I need some help please.

Please excuse my lack of knowledge I have only just started learning Java.

```
 Object[][] data  = {
                          {"dd/mm/yyyy", new Double(5), new Boolean(false), 
                          {"21/12/2013",  new Double(5), new Boolean(false)};
                    }

   String    sDividendDate1       =   (String)data[0][0];
   Double    dDividend1           =   (Double)data[0][1];


try
 {
       FileWriter file = new FileWriter(NewCodeFile);
       BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(file);
       buffer.write(sDividendDate1);
       buffer.newLine();
       **buffer.write(sDividend1);  /*This is where the compiler does not like 
       [I think it is because I am trying to write a double variable into a char 
       text buffer?]**/
}
```

How do I write the double value stored in dDividend1 in the same file after 
 I have written sDividendDate1 into the same file.
 Any help is always greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Kind Regards
 Stephen

Comment: Are you trying to write is as text or in binary form?

Comment: If you have found an answer that suits your needs in the answers provided, please mark the answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try `String.valueOf(sDividend1)`or `Double.toString(...)`.

You might also want to check `java.text.NumberFormat`.

Comment: "Not working" is **not** a detailed and helpful error description.

Answer (score 1):

Stephen,
Based on your code above you have referenced an undeclared variable:

```
Object[][] data = { 
    {
        {
            "dd/mm/yyyy", 
            new Double(5), 
            new Boolean(false)
        },
        {
             "21/12/2013", 
             new Double(5), 
             new Boolean(false)
        }
    };

    String sDividendDate1 = (String)data[0][0]; 
    Double dDividend1 = (Double)data[0][1];

    try { 
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(NewCodeFile); 
        BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(file);
        buffer.write(sDividendDate1);
        buffer.newLine();
        buffer.write(dDividend1); /* you had this as sDividend1 which was not declared */
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        //catch logic here
    }
```

Comment: Additionally, your declaration of the array 'data' was incorrect.  I've updated the declaration to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write Objects in a binary representation you should use an [ObjectOutputStream](http://www.jdk5.ru/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)